# How i can make textfield editable at middle of text

Tags: javascript

```
//The porpost of this function is prevent user type any thing intext field except 0-9 and .

//For recieve value,event and keycode from text field.    
    function allowOnlyFloatingPointNumbers(textbox,val,key)
        {
        var MaxLen = 11;
        var val2 = val.replace(/,/g,"");
        var letterNumber = /^[0-9.]+$/;
         if((val2.match(letterNumber)))
          {
                textbox.value = val;
          }
        else
          {
                textbox.value = val.substr(0,val.length-1);
                return;
          }

            var valtmp = val;
            if(valtmp.indexOf(".")<0)
            {
                if(valtmp.replace(/,/g,"").length>MaxLen)
                {
                    textbox.value = addCommas(val.substr(0,val.length-1));
                }
                else
                {
                    textbox.value = addCommas(valtmp.replace(/,/g,""));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                val = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");         // strip non-digit chars
                textbox.value = addCommas(val);            // replace textbox value
                var indx = val.indexOf(".");
                if(indx>-1)
                {
                    var lng = val.substr(indx+1).length;
                    if(lng>2)
                    {
                        textbox.value = addCommas(val.substr(0,val.length-1));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    function addCommas(nStr)
                {
                        nStr += "";
                        x = nStr.split(".");
                        x1 = x[0];
                        x2 = x.length > 1 ? "." + x[1] : "";
                        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
                        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, "$1" + "," + "$2");
                        }
                        return x1 + x2;
                }
```

Now if i type 987654321 it will be 987,654,321in textbox

but if i need to edit in middle of text like in change 5 to 0
the text will be 987,643,210 zero is insert at end of text
I need it to be 987,604,321 which part of the function that i should change.

I use IE 9.

Here is example http://jsbin.com/arivug/1

Comment: Could you possibly provide a working example with markup on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Well, I made a quick demo myself.  I used the oninput event that is compatible with IE9.  Seems to work as expected with just a few bugs that would need ironed out.  Please elaborate in your question on what exactly the situation is and how to recreate it. http://jsbin.com/ajubow/1

Comment: Umm it is not the same as i want the textfield is accept any thing.
but from function above it will accept only number and . and insert commas"," for every 3 digits. I try to give an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net by i cannot pass value of textfield to function and let function set value of textfield.

Comment: This http://jsbin.com/arivug/1 this is my currently work
if you try to edit or change some digits in the middle the new digit will be on the end of textfield

Comment: I got slightly bored and just completely reworked it using oninput.  While this is not what you were asking for, I thought it might help.  If it does meet all your needs, feel free to use it and I'll post it as an answer.  [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/nX2ke/1) and [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nX2ke/1/show)